# Anderes Wort für »herumprobieren«

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Gibt es für *herumprobieren* ein bildungssprachliches Synonym? Also ein Wort, das man in einer akademischen Arbeit verwenden kann? Oder eine kurze Umschreibung?

Es geht um den Kontext, dass man manche Probleme, sei es auf die Mathematik bezogen oder im echten Leben, durch Probieren bzw. Herumprobieren lösen kann.

Wenn ich z.B. eine Nullstelle einer Funktion rate und z.B. 0, 1, 2, 3 probiere, dann habe ich doch herumprobiert.

In Bezug auf hiergiltdiestfus Antwort: *Experimentieren* würde man in diesem Kontext doch nicht sagen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Einzige mir bekannte Beschreibungen dieser generellen Herangehensweise sind *[Versuch und Irrtum](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22Versuch+und+Irrtum%22)* bzw. das eingedeutschte *[Trial and Error](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trial_and_Error_Methode)* sowie *[Probieren](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=Probieren+Nullstellen)* (aber nicht *Herumprobieren).* Also zum Beispiel:

> Die Nullstelle wurde über Versuch und Irrtum gefunden.
>
> Die Nullstelle wurde mit einer Trial-and-Error-Methode gefunden
>
> Die Nullstelle wurde über Probieren gefunden.

Für den konkreten Fall können *probieren* (aber nicht *herumprobieren)* oder auch *(aus)[testen](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?start=20&q=%22Testen%22+NUllstelle)* als Verben verwendt werden, also zum Beispiel:

> Ein Testen der verbleibenden 542 Kandidaten ergab, dass 23 die Nullstelle ist.
>
> Die Nullstellen 0, 1, 2 und 3 wurden probiert.

Comment: "austesten" halte ich für ein umgangssprachliches Synonym für "ausprobieren". Und "testen" ist in vielen Diziplinen ein sehrwohl definiertes Vorgehen.

Comment: @alk: *Austesten* ist im wissenschaftlichen Kontext [durchaus gebräuchlich](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=austesten), wird also zumindest nicht in allen Disziplinen als Umgangssprache angesehen. — *Und "testen" ist in vielen Diziplinen ein sehrwohl definiertes Vorgehen.* – Und was folgt daraus?

Comment: Es folgt, dass "testen" nix mit (zufälligem, nicht korreliertem, unabhängigem) "probieren" zu tun hat.

Comment: Ausserdem halte ich "Versuch und Irrtum" für die Übersetzung einer Phrase, die so im Deutschen vorher nicht existierte.

Comment: @alk: *Es folgt, dass "testen" nix mit (zufälligem, nicht korreliertem, unabhängigem) "probieren" zu tun hat.* – Hat das Raten von Nullstellen meistens auch nicht (man kann die Anzahl der Kandidaten leicht auf eine überschaubare Menge reduzieren).

Comment: @alk: *Ausserdem halte ich "Versuch und Irrtum" für die Übersetzung einer Phrase, die so im Deutschen vorher nicht existierte.* – “vorher” in Bezug auf was? [Die Phrase scheint schon etwas länger im Gebrauch zu sein.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Versuch+und+Irrtum&year_start=1900&year_end=2015&corpus=20)

Answer (score 4):

Für eine akademische Arbeit würde ich

> heuristisches Verfahren

vorschlagen, vgl. [Wikipedia: Heuristik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristik). *Trial and Error* ist zwar nur eine Untermenge davon, aber der Begriff hat das passende Sprachniveau und ermöglicht zudem das Kaschieren der genau verwendeten Methode. Bei Bedarf **kann** man es natürlich auch weiter ausführen, muss das aber nicht tun, weswegen der Begriff auch vom Marketing gerne verwendet wird (klassisches Beispiel: Virenscanner).

Answer (score 2):

Will man nicht auf das einfache "probieren" zurückgreifen, so ist es wohl ratsam, schlicht zu behaupten, man habe verschiedene, bei Nullstellen zum Beispiel durch eine grafische Darstellung (in einer Wissenschaftlichen Arbeit sollte man sich vielleicht nicht auf "Intuition" berufen) begründete, Hypothesen getestet und die Ergebnisse verglichen.

Das ist zumindest die wissenschaftlichste Formulierung für "(herum)probieren": Ich bilde eine Hypothese und teste diese auf Plausibilität. Das ist eigentlich nichts anderes als "experimentieren", betont aber den vorläufigen, eher zufälligen Charakter. Experimente sind meist in komplexere konzeptuelle Räume eingebettet als "Nullstellen raten".

Answer (score 1):

*Experimentieren* wäre wohl das naheliegende, wissenschaftliche Herumprobieren.

Comment: Gibt es nicht einen Unterschied zwischen probieren und experementieren? http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumexperimentieren http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumprobieren

Comment: *Experimentieren* ist nur in niederen Sprachregistern synonym zu *Herumprobieren.* In höheren Sprachregistern oder im wissenschaftlichen Kontext heißt *Probieren,* dass man irgendetwas konkretes Problem hat und etwas tut, von dem man nicht weiß aber hofft, ob es dieses Problem zu löst. *Experimentieren* hingegen ist das Herausfinden von Fakten über gezielte Messungen und Prozeduren.

Comment: Genau so hatte ich das auch gesehen. Ich habe meine Frage nochmal aktualisiert und den Kontext erklärt, für den ich ein bildungssprachliches Synonym suche.

Answer (score 0):

In einigen Fällen mag **iterativ** passen, vor allem wenn man ein Verfahren hat, bei dem man sich der passenden Lösung schrittweise annähert, etwa bei der Suche nach der Wurzel einer Zahl, wenn die eine probierte Zahl zu klein und die nächste zu groß war und man dann eine Zahl in der Mitte sucht.

Comment: Hat aber nix mit "probieren", im Sinne unajängiger Tests zu tun.

Comment: @alk: Was meinst Du mit "unabhängigen Tests"? In der Fragestellung sehe ich solche nicht gefordert. Wenn ich ohne Wikipedia und Rechner die Wurzel von 342 suchen soll, und es genügt die Ganzzahl zu finden, die der Lösung am nächsten kommt, dann überschlage ich, dass 20*20=400 in der Nähe ist, und probiere 19*19. Ist das zu groß probiere ich 18*18 usw. Das ist doch Probieren. Würdest Du sagen Probieren ist es nur, wenn ich wild und zufällig wähle, auch mal 7*7 und 4.500*4.500?

Comment: Ja, "probieren" schliesst Systematik, wie zB. eine Iteration, aus.

Comment: @alk: Da stimmen wir nicht überein.